# On IMG right click, presented with "bookmark this page" "save page as" instead of typical "save img as"

Tags: image, html

I've looked around the question forum to find an answer, but it doesn't look like anyone has run across this problem before. So if I missed it, I'm sorry for wasting your time!

Like I indicated in the title of the question, my `IMG` right-click functionality is not working. It seems as if the browser is not recognizing the `img element`. It must be something to do with the `Pinterest Pin It plugin` I have. If you press reload/refresh and right-click the image (before the JS has loaded), you can see the normal `save as image` options when you right-click. But once the page has fully loaded, you cannot.

I inspected it in Firebug and maybe it has something to do with the `pin it overlay` span? I'm not sure.

Has anyone heard of this issue before? I would really appreciate any guidance. Maybe I'm just searching the wrong keywords. Thanks so much.

Here is my Web site: http://brightontheday.com

Comment: From what I could pull from the selection source, you'd have to see what the `class` codes are set to in `class="size-full wp-image-11144 alignnone"` those are the classes your image is set to, if that info didn't show up in Firebug.

Comment: @Fred what do you mean by "what the class codes are set to"?

Comment: The class of the image itself it's set to, which is related to `CSS` / stylesheet. That might have something to do with it, and/or in a `JS` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [THIS PLUGIN](http://mrsztuczkens.me/jpibfi/) instead and did not have the issue anymore!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're referring to the image on your page that says "Floral Frenzy" over it, which, when you mouseover it shows the "PIN" overlay that Pinterest injects.

You're pretty close in asserting that Pinterest is either the cause or related. There's a span overlay sitting on top of your img:

```
<span class="pinit-overlay alignnone" style="height: 714px; width: 466px; ...
```

So that overlay is what's getting right-clicked and since that's not an img, you're getting the same right-click menu you'd get for right-clicking a blank area of the page.

Generally speaking you can inspect problems like this with Chrome by right-clicking as you have and clicking Inspect Element, which will show you a DOM tree and what tag you're actually over right now. Chrome will take you straight to the problem span, in this case.

I don't work with Pinterest enough to know whether this overlay is part of Pinterest, something you've added, or maybe something you can configure if it is injected by Pinterest, but as a brute-force hack it seems clear you could isolate it to a small area around the actual pin via CSS like:

```
span.pinit-overlay {
    width: 100px !important; height: 66px !important;
}
```

That hack will force the overlay to be just a tad larger (4px) than the actual pin button it applies, so most of the image will still be on top and get the standard right-click menu, and the pin button keeps working.

Interestingly despite this hack the Pin button remains just as discoverable though, still appearing when you mouseover any part of the image, which really makes me question why the overlay is placed there at all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I ended up using another plugin and then my problem went away! Thanks so much for all the help though!